# How do I migrate dates?

Tags: migrations, datetime

In my Drupal 7 site, the date is stored in the database as *2020-08-10 00:00:00*.

When I migrate those dates without any formatting (`field_blog_post_date: field_blog_post_date`), the date is migrated into the Drupal 8 table with the same exact formatting. However, it doesn't show when a node is viewed.

I tried to use a `format_date` plugin.

```yaml
field_blog_post_date: 
  plugin: format_date
  source: field_blog_post_date
  from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
  to_format: 'Y-m-d'
```

When I use it, it causes the following error.

> DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
> DateTimePlus.php:251

Comment: Side question, why are you using `field_blog_post_date` rather than the node's created date?

Comment: its an additional date which indicates when they want it to be posted.

Comment: Does the D8 database value look as expected? Or does it fail to import?

Comment: it imports but with this structure.2020-08-10 00:00:00 in the database.  but. doesn show upon viewing the. content in the edit mode

Comment: Since it's Date only, it needs to be `2020-08-10` in the D8 db, otherwise it won't display. For some reason its failing to re-format.

Comment: i know that is what im trying to solve with this question .

Comment: In the D7 db does it show as `2020-08-10 00:00:00`?

Comment: yes it shows as 2020-08-10 00:00:00 in the d7 database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked! found the answer here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923723#comment-12343660

```
 field_blog_post_date: 
        plugin: iterator
        source: field_blog_post_date
        process:
          value:
            plugin: substr
            source: value
            start: 0
            length: 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Also from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923723#comment-13141671

```
field_blog_post_date:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_blog_post_date
    process:
      value:
        plugin: format_date
        from_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
        to_format: 'Y-m-d'
        source: value
```

Should work